# API to get detailed call logs in sinch

Tags: sinch

I have developed a php VoIP web application using Sinch sdk, and I want to show to the admin some statistics and reports, There are any restful API to get logs details of the app to app calls to display it within my php application?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Sinch Voice REST API**
https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/#UserCallReport